# dependency dropped,No such file or directory

Tags: android-ndk

there!

I force the compiler to rebuild(STLPORT_FORCE_REBUILD := true in 
Application.mk) the stlport, the following error message come up:

```
libstlport_shared.so dependency dropped. 
SharedLibrary  : libstlport_shared.so 
arm-linux-androideabi-g++.exe: D:/Eclipse/Decoder/obj/local/armeabi/ 
libstlport_shared.so: No such file or directory 
make: *** [/cygdrive/d/Eclipse/Decoder/obj/local/armeabi/ 
libstlport_shared.so] Error 1
```

This message only show up when I force a rebuild in android-ndk- 
r5c,while in the latest android-ndk-r6, it will show up without 
STLPORT_FORCE_REBUILD := true in the Application.mk.

Any idea on how to deal with dependency dropped? 
Any help appreciated! 
Jiabin